# Zend form setAction submits wrong url

Tags: php, zend-framework

**My Zend form has the following code:**

```
$this->setAction('/contact/index')->setMethod('post');
```

The form displays fine here:

> localhost/my_project/public/contact/index

But, form submits to:

> localhost/contact/index
>   Instead of:
>   localhost/my_project/public/contact/index

How do I fix this and is it a server config issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that it doesn't use baseurl

The easiest solution is to set the action in the view

```
//view.phtml
$form= $this->form; //Comes from controller or create a new instance
$form->setAction($this->baseUrl("contact/index"));
echo $form;
```

You can also subclass Zend_Form and modify setAction to use baseurl

You can also set the view of the form

```
class Application_Form_Something extends...{
      protect $_view;
      function setView($view){
        $this->_view->$view;
      }
      function setAction($url){
          parent::setAction($this->_view->baseUrl($url));
      }

}

//And in controller:

$form->setView($this->view);
```

On a related note, I found another way of setting baseurl. This seems to be the best one so far, although I am not sure if it is the correct way of doing it.

```
class Application_Form_Something extends...{

      function setAction($url){
        $baseUrlHelper= new Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl();
          parent::setAction($baseUrlHelper->baseUrl($url));
      }
}
```

You can also do this in the init method itself.

Comment: Thank you! But: isn't setting the action in the view injecting business logic in the view?

Comment: Yes it is. You can do this in the controller too. $this->view->baseUrl instead of $this->baseUrl.
Another alternative is to set the view for the form. see updated answer

Comment: mostly, I submit to the same url as the one rendering a form, so the setAction method is rarely used in my applications